# How to handle multiple component updating same state?

Tags: react-redux

I have a page which is composed of different components and all those components depend on the same redux state.

How should I handle checking and updating of the state?
The state is setting/checking if the user is authenticated, if not, it will call an API (side-effect) which will authenticate to the API.

What I don't want to happen is all those components try to call the API with same set of requests since they're basically checking/updating same thing. But those component is dependent on that state.

What is the common/popular approach in handling states in these kind of situations.

Comment: You want to update the state as soon as the first fetch starts so that it has “isLoading” or something stored.  Make all of your requests conditional so that they won’t begin if “isLoading” is already true.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you need to send you request's response to all components as props (mapDispatchToProps) and then every component that has that prop will update.

Comment: Yes, correct. But my concern is for example I have a custom hook that calls the authenticate api which dispatch a reducer to update the auth state, then that custom hook is called by `useEffect` of all components to retrieve the auth state. My concern is if all components mount simultaneously and might fire X number of requests to API because all those components are using the same hook. Is there a pattern that I can use to not let all components call the API?

Comment: could you please put here your custom hook?

Answer (score 0):

You need to dispatch action and set the state accordingly with respect to response data and Just apply onFocusListener in all the screens where you are using this state.
Every time when you will move to a particular screen It will update according to the new state.

Here is the example for Listener

```
  useEffect(() => {
const loads = props.navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
});
return () => {
    loads
}}, [props.navigation]);
```